Create a form that automatically generate fields according to a generic Type
I'm using the Form Telerik component and I would like to use the template customization for every form item. Now, I need to create a component called InsertEntity which take a type TEntity as input and then recreate the form according to the fields of the properties of TEntity. The problem here is that i'm not able to use the @bind-value with the generic type. I follow also this tutorial: Blazor : is it possible to bind a generic item to a property by its name using reflection? but it doesn't work with TelerikTextBox.
I would like a demo from you with a form that dynamically show the property of a type using the customization template of the form...
Something like the code attached....
@inject IStringLocalizer<InsertEntity<TEntity>> Localizer

@typeparam TEntity where TEntity : class, IValidable<TEntity>, IHub<TEntity>, new()

<TelerikForm EditContext="@FormEditContext" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmitHandler" Class="m-auto mb-5" Model="@EditableEntityDTO" Columns="@(ScreenSize == MediaQuery.Medium ? 1 : 2)" ColumnSpacing="25px" Width="80%">
    <FormValidation>
        <TelerikValidationSummary>
            <Template>
                <div class="custom-validation-message" style="color:red">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomValidationMessage))
                    {
                        <div>
                            <TelerikSvgIcon Icon="@SvgIcon.XOutline" />
                            <span>@Localizer[CustomValidationMessage]</span>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </Template>
        </TelerikValidationSummary>
    </FormValidation>

    <FormItems>
        @{
            foreach (var property in Properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(System.String))
                {
                    <FormItem Field="@nameof(property.Name)">
                        <Template>
                            <label for="@nameof(property)" class="k-label k-form-label">@(ModelHelper.GetAttributeValue<TEntity, DisplayAttribute>(property.Name))</label>
                            <div class="k-form-field-wrap">
                                <TelerikTextBox Placeholder=@(ModelHelper.GetAttributeValue<TEntity, PlaceholderAttribute>(nameof(property)))
                                            @bind-Value="????????????????" />

                                <TelerikValidationMessage For="@(() => property)" />
                            </div>
                        </Template>
                    </FormItem>
                }
                else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {

                }
                else if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    </FormItems>

</TelerikForm>


[Polite] Generic Forms and components seem like a gread idea.  ChatGPT will tell me how [I couldn't resist that dig!]  There's a reason the Internet is not awash with projects and tutorials on the subject.  Why the major component houses don't have great looking ones.  At first glance, it looks easy.  We focus on the TextField.  As we branch out into numerics, then dates things start to get complicated.  Then comes selects and checkboxes and ...  Complexity spirals out of control.  The options list gets enormous. And if you get even close, what do you get.  A bland looking thing with poor UX.

My approach is to build all the button control, form control etc into boilerplate code so my form is just about what fields to display and how to display them.
